# url() not providing links to correct language alias using i18n in D7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

We have a site that features two languages, EN (primary/default) and JA.  On one content page, we link to another node using it's `nid`: `url('node/123')`.  In EN, this returns the alias and not the node based url.  When in the JA language, this returns a url like `/ja/node/123` which then shows text in the EN variant when we expect JA.  There are aliases set for both EN and JA, which both point to the same desired URL like: `/products/new-fancy-product` and their respective node id urls.  In EN, `url` returns this alias correctly.

Also, if I change `/products/new-fancy-product` to `/ja/products/new-fancy-product` in the address bar, I get the correct JA version of the page as I want.

Why is `url` not returning me the correct alias instead of the node id path, which then just shows EN content?

Answer (score 0):

Use [l() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) to generate a link.

> Formats an internal or external URL link as an HTML anchor tag.
>
> This function correctly handles aliased paths and adds an 'active'
>   class attribute to links that point to the current page (for theming),
>   so all internal links output by modules should be generated by this
>   function if possible.

Comment: This just appears to wrap a call to `url` which isn't working.  How will this help?

Comment: @Chris have you actually tried using l() instead of url()?

Comment: Yes, it returns the sam thing as `url` except with link fully built and ready for use in html: `/ja/node/123`.  This still gives me the english version, and doesn't properly resolve the alias which should be `/ja/products/new-fancy-product`